# How can I speed up tests with PHPUnit running with Xdebug

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

I'm running test on `PHPUnit` using `Xdebug` for generating coverage and it is very slow.

I tried using `PHPdbg` but that leads to memory errors.

I was told that I can create a filter file, and that should help. Can anyone explain to me how that would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://phpunit.de/documentation.html) for PHPUnit has information on [speeding up code coverage with Xdebug](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code-coverage-analysis.html#speeding-up-code-coverage-with-xdebug). For more background information I recommend this [article](https://thephp.cc/news/2019/01/faster-code-coverage).

That being said, I recommend having a look at [PCOV](https://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2019/01/running-for-coverage.html) for even faster code coverage data collection for PHP and PHPUnit.